# ¿Cómo puedo llenar mi select con datos de una API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario para "editar" el contenido de producto, y pude hacer que se carguen los valores que tiene el producto en los inputs, pero en el select, siempre carga la opción "0" por defecto como se puede ver en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo si miro en lo que me devuelve el api, esta bien y allí esta el producto con su respectiva categoría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo que uso para llenar estos campos:

```
$.get('../api/v1/productos/' + id_producto, {}, function(returnedData){
        $("#nombre").attr('value', returnedData["producto"]["nombre"]);
        $("#id_categoria").val(returnedData["producto"]["categoria"]["id_categoria"]);
        $("#descripcion").attr('value', returnedData["producto"]["descripcion"]);
    });
```

El $("#id_categoria") es el que no esta funcionando como deberia.

La idea es que cuando entre para editar, la categoria respectiva este ya seleccionada (en este caso deberia ser "categoria 1" y no "Seleccionar categoria").

Aqui esta el select que utilizo:

```
<select style="width:100%" id="id_categoria" class="select2_normal form-control"><option value="0">Seleccionar Categoría</option></select>
```

Aprecio la ayuda gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que nada hay que ver si cada elemento **option** del **select** tiene configurado el atributo **value**, de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="my_custom_list">
  <select id = "id_categoria">
    <option value="1">Categoría 1</option>
    <option value="2">Categoría 2</option>
    <option value="3">Categoría 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Los valores del atributo **value** deben corresponderse con el valor del campo **id_categoria** que estás intentando usar. Esto es importante ya que al momento de usar el método de jQuery val() va a sel el atributo **value** el que nos servirá para mostrar una categoría específica, de esta manera:

```
var selectedCategory = returnedData["producto"]["categoria"]["id_categoria"];
$("#id_categoria").val(selectedCategory );
```

Donde el valor de **selectedCategory** para este ejemplo debería ser un id_categoria válido.

Saludos

Comment: Ya hice eso, probe tambien como respondiste, la variable devuelve el id correcto "1" pero igual sigue sin salir seleccionada :(

Comment: Que tal Juan, de pronto viste en la consola si obtienes algún error?

Comment: No, no sale ningun error en consola :(

Comment: Hola Juan, la verdad acabo de probar un ejemplo sencillo y si funciona correctamente, si el objecto select está cargando correctamente todas las categorías no hay ningún problema.

Comment: Bueno no entiendo por que me sigue cargando solo la opcion 0 de seleccione categoria :/

Comment: Otra buena opción es hacer un debug en las herramientas de desarrollo (F12), en la sección **Sources** y pones un punto de interrupción en la parte del seteo de la categoría, a veces haciendo esto nos damos cuenta de posibles errores o inconsistencias.

Comment: Al parecer por algun motivo la clase de select "select2_normal form-control" no funcionaba asi que la deje como una class "form-control" y ahi ya funciono :)